# Execute CMD from Scheduler Task

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

I followed below article to set a reminder
https://www.howtogeek.com/136894/how-to-create-popup-reminders-with-no-additional-software/

Task triggered as per specified time but command prompt window doesn't stay open instead it close immediately closed

I put below in Add Argument field
/C TITLE Read How-To Geek Reminder&ECHO.TIMEOUT 120

"press a key to continue" message is not showing for me

Am I missing something?

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything in a .bat file save it into a directory of you preference, and do the Windows task scheduling as shown in the tutorial except calling the CMD and passing arguments just place the path + *.bat file in the Program/Script textbox of the task scheduler.

Cheers